# Template for custom admin panel tab Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, magento1.9.2.4

I've created a module which creates a custom tab in the admin panel but I've not been able to display the required data.`

This is my config.xml file

Path: app/code/community/JR/CreateAdminController/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <JR_CreateAdminController>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </JR_CreateAdminController>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <jr_createadmincontroller>
            <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
            <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
        </jr_createadmincontroller>
    </helpers>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <foo_bar before="Mage_Adminhtml">JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</foo_bar>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

This is my adminhtml.xml file

path: app/code/community/JR/CreateAdminController/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <mycustomtab module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
        <title>My Custom Tab</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <index module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
                <title>Index Action</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/custom</action>
            </index>
            <list module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
                <title>List Action</title>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/custom/list</action>
            </list>
        </children>
    </mycustomtab>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <custom translate="title" module="jr_createadmincontroller">
                    <title>My Controller</title>
                    <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <index translate="title">
                            <title>Index Action</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </index>
                        <list translate="title">
                            <title>List Action</title>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        </list>
                    </children>
                </custom>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

This is my CustomController.php file

Path: app/code/community/JR/CreateAdminController/controllers/Adminhtml

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends       Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
        ->_title($this->__('Index Action'));

    // my stuff

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function listAction()
{

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
        ->_title($this->__('List Action'));

        //var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        //die();
    // my stuff
        echo "string";

    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

This is my jr_createadmincontroller.xml file

path:app/design/adminhtml/default/default/jr_createadmincontroller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<adminhtml_custom_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom_index" template="custom/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_custom_index>
<adminhtml_custom_list>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom_list" template="custom/list.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_custom_list>

</layout>
```

The Path of Custom folder is app/design/adminhtml/default/default/Template/Custom

There is index.phtml and list.phtml

But nothing showing in admin panel screen
[image]

Comment: Please enable developer mode of your magento so that you can see the exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is: where are your block classes? To show stuff you need both a controller and a block. And you need to define the blocks for the layout handle as well. The code you're using now is rendered correctly, but you didn't define any content.

I see you used the code from [Bubblecode](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/02/08/magento-create-your-own-admin-controller-in-a-new-tab/), which also has comments that the code isn't working.

An extension that shows stuff in any page, requires at least a Controller (which you already have), a Block class and a helper (for translations, etc).

To define your blocks you need to add this in your `config.xml` file between the `<global></global>` tags:

```
<blocks>
    <jr_createadmincontroller>
        <class>JR_CreateAdminController_Block</class>
    </jr_createadmincontroller>
</blocks>
```

After that, you will need to create a custom layout file, which will be used to load the blocks into your page. To do this, you need the following things:

**Define adminhtml layout file**
In your `config.xml` create a section `<adminhtml>` after the closing tag for `<global>`:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <jr_createadmincontroller>
                <file>jr_createadmincontroller.xml</file>
            </jr_createadmincontroller>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Now you need to create this layout XML file, which should be located at `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/jr_customcontroller.xml`. The code you need in this file will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_createadmincontroller_custom_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="jr_createadmincontroller/adminhtml_custom" name="name.of.your.block" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_createadmincontroller_custom_index>
</layout>
```

After this, you might have to create templates as well, or you should use the default grid functionality, based on the ones Magento uses for the products, CMS pages, etc.

Of course, the above code doesn't work out of the box, but I hope it will give you a better understanding of what you need to get content into your own adminhtml controller.

Comment: I have also defined custom template
path:app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\custom
1. index.phtml
2. list.phtml
But its not working

Comment: What do you want to end up with? Question is if you need a custom template. Magento has the option to add a grid page without setting a template. For that, you might want to check out this post by Inchoo: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Comment: Thankyou :) it helps alot

Answer (score -2):

Error resolved by putting the layout code in **config.xml** file below ending tag of **Global**

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <jr_createadmincontroller>
                <file>jr_createadmincontroller.xml</file>
            </jr_createadmincontroller>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

and by putting the **jr_createadmincontroller.xml** file into

**Path:** app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/jr_createadmincontroller.xml

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. You could have just marked my answer as the solution instead of copying it partially as a new answer.